# Get DataGridRow After Sorting Rows

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview

In vb.net or c# DataGridViews is there a built-in way to always have a row assigned to an id even after sorting the rows.

Using

```vb
For Each row In DataGridView1.Rows
    debug.writeline(row.cells(0).value)
Next
```

is subject to the rows current position and not the position they were added.

I know you can add a hidden id column and increment it every time you add a row but I didn't know if there was a built-in way to do this.

*edit*

I have a list of values that fill out the data grid view then the grid view can be edited and after the edit, the list of values needs to be updated. So if you have a row that says "Toyota", "Yellow" and you Change it to "Toyota","Red" id want the index of "Toyota","Yellow" to become "Toyota", "Red"

Basically a sql table but in list(of string()) form.

Comment: I have a list of values that fill out the data grid view then the grid view can be edited and after the edit, the list of values needs to be updated. So if you have a row that says "Toyota", "Yellow" and you Change it to "Toyota","Red" id want the index of "Toyota","Yellow" to become "Toyota", "Red"..Basically a sql table but in list(of string()) form. @o_O

Comment: If the data is in a collection, work with the collection/datasource not the control.  Controls are just how we display data to users.

Answer (score 0):

(Probably)　In an unbound DataGridView, it is likely that you can use HashCode as Id for each row.

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
        dgv.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());

        dgv.Rows.Add("key1", "value1");
        dgv.Rows.Add("key2", "value2");
        dgv.Rows.Add("key3", "value3");

        Debug.Print("original");
        dispHash();

        /*sorting*/
        dgv.Sort(dgv.Columns[1], ListSortDirection.Descending);

        Debug.Print("sorted");
        dispHash();

        /*edit*/
        dgv[1, 2].Value = "changed";
        Debug.Print("edited");
        dispHash();

        /*deleted*/
        dgv.Rows.Remove(dgv.Rows[1]);
        Debug.Print("removed");
        dispHash();

        /*add*/
        dgv.Rows.Add("key4", "value4");
        Debug.Print("add");
        dispHash();
    }

    private void dispHash()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            Debug.Print(row.Cells[0].Value + ":" + row.GetHashCode());
        }
    }
```

original
key1:41014879
key2:3888474
key3:25209742
:26966483

sorted
key3:25209742
key2:3888474
key1:41014879
:26966483

edited
key3:25209742
key2:3888474
key1:41014879
:26966483

removed
key3:25209742
key1:41014879
:26966483

add
key3:25209742
key1:41014879
key4:31884011
:26966483